Kubernetes RWO PersistentVolume node semantics with ceph-rbd
Context:
Imagine I have a StatefulSet in a multi-node cluster, using a VolumeClaimTemplate to auto-provision storage using a rbd.csi.ceph.com provisioner using RWO.
At runtime, I'll have I have something like this:

A pod named my-app-1, running on node-A
A PV & PVC named my-app-1, which are both referenced by that single pod, and nothing else

Question:
If I need to evict the pod from node-A, under RWO, will that storage be reattached to my-app-1 when it comes back up on node-B? On one hand, the PV/PVC won't have any references from node-a, but on the other hand, the docs aren't quite clear, because the node has now changed, and I'm not sure if a volume initially associated with node-A will be bound to that node forever?

the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node.
ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to access the
volume when the pods are running on the same node. For single pod
access, please see ReadWriteOncePod.

